# How to read declaring an array size?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an array declaration which results in 144 slots.
I don't understand how I've got to this number. Also, what means all those commas between numbers?

```
Dim arr4(1, 5, 5, 0 To 1) As Long
    Debug.Print ArraySize(arr4)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `,` denotes a new dimension.  So `arr4` has 4 dimensions.

When using `0 to 1` it is saying that the fourth dimension has two, 0 and 1

When using just one number `5` then the starting point is assumed `0` unless changed in the settings, so there are `6` in that dimension: `0,1,2,3,4,5`

The reason there are 144 is because `2*6*6*2=144`

Think of it this way.

1st dimension is rows with two row (0,1)
2nd dimension is columns with 6 columns (0,1,2,3,4,5)
3rd dimension create 6 sheets of the above configuration (0,1,2,3,4,5)
4th dimension create 2 workbooks with each having 6 sheets with 12 cells (0,1)

Thus there is 144 cells in which to put data.